# Weird thing in references/bibliography page

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, labels

I'm writing my thesis but I have a huge problem. I'm using BibTeX to make the bibliography, but when I run my project,in the references page of my pdf created file I have beside the number of the record (I'm using plain style) a label with the record's key name
***I don't know why there is this label, and I want to hide it.
How can I do?***

In my main `.tex` file I use:

```
 \usepackage{cite}

    %---------------------BEGIN BIBLIOGRAFIA----------------------------

    \newpage

    \nocite{*}

    \bibliographystyle{plain}

    \bibliography{bibliography}

    %---------------------END BIBLIOGRAFIA------------------------------
```

And in `bibliography.bib` I have (at the moment) only one record:

```
@article{jor:1,

author = {Andreas Jordan and Regina Scholz and Peter Wust and Horst Fakhling and Roland 
Felix},

title = {Magnetic fluid hyperthermia ({M}{F}{H}): Cancer treatment with
AC magnetic field induced excitation of biocompatible
superparamagnetic nanoparticles},

journal = {Journal of Magnetism and Magnetic Materials},

year = 1999,

volume = {201},

pages = {413-419}

}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: With the information that you give, I can't see any reason why the citekey should appear. Can you please post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: do you have showkeys or showlabels or showtags package loaded?

Comment: I'm new here, and i can't share an image that shows the problem. In the pdf, beside the citation, a borded label with the record key appears and I don't know why.

Comment: Yeah, i have the "showkeys" package loaded. Is that the problem?

Comment: I unloaded that package and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `showkeys` is a debugging package so that while drafting citations and label/ref show the internal key name.

Answer (score 3):

`showkeys` is a debugging package so that while drafting citations and label/ref show the internal key name. For the final versions you should remove it or use

```
\usepackage[final]{showkeys}
```